# raising jquery deferred.then() once all deferred objects have been resolved

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

i have two javascript functions, `save()` and `saveAll()`, set up as below:

```
function save(data) {
    return $.post('/save', data);
}

function saveAll(callback) {
    var dataArray = [];
    $.each(dataArray, function() {
        save(this);
    });
    callback();
}
```

i'm interested in modifying `saveAll()` so that it leverages jquery deferred objects, and raises the `callback` function once all `save()` operations have completed.  however, i'm unsure of the exact syntax... specifically with relation to the $.each() inside of the $.when().  would it be something like this?

```
function saveAll(callback) {
    var dataArray = [];
    $.when(
        $.each(dataArray, function() {
            return save(this);
        })
    ).then(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

as Eli pointed out, $.when() accepts a comma separated list of arguments and not an array.  using `Function.apply()` to pass in the array seems to do the trick.

```
function saveAll(callback) {
    var dataArray = [], deferreds = [];
    $.each(dataArray, function() {
        deferreds.push( save() );
    });

    $.when.apply(window, deferreds).then(callback);
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic, was looking for just this. I'm suprised jQuery doesn't allow for an array of deferred objects natively.

Comment: Just be careful, because a little known fact about $.when is that it will immediately resolve if any one of the arguments is rejected/failed, without waiting for the rest! It's true :) And unexpected, if you ask me. I wrote a $.whenAll() that always waits for all the arguments to resolve, regardless of success/fail status: http://jsfiddle.net/InfinitiesLoop/yQsYK/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass a comma-separated list of deferred objects to `$.when` and `.then` will execute once they all have resolved.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is that `$.each` is returning your `dataArray`, not a list of `Deferred` objects like you want to feed to `$.when`.

Comment: you're right, the return value from $.each() is not what i wanted. thanks.